# How can I iterate over a list of dictionaries and create new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over a list of dictionaries below, and where the 'name' == 'name' of another dict, the prices (in this case its the value of 'Variant OG' or 'Bad Axe') are put into a single dict.

```
[{'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1354, 'item': 'Giardiniera', 'Variant OG': 5.0},
 {'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1355, 'item': 'Sweet Peppers', 'Variant OG': 5.0},
 {'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1334, 'item': 'Hot Bar Serving Hardware', 'Variant OG': 5.0},
 {'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1354, 'item': 'Giardiniera', 'Bad Axe': 1.0},
 {'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1355, 'item': 'Sweet Peppers', 'Bad Axe': 1.0},
 {'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1334, 'item': 'Hot Bar Serving Hardware', 'Bad Axe': 1.0}]
```

Basically, all same menu items are in the same dict, but also have their different prices included

Ideally, the end result would look like

```
{'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1354, 'item': 'Giardiniera', 'Variant OG': 5.0, 'Bad Axe': 1.0}
{'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1355, 'item': 'Sweet Peppers', 'Variant OG': 5.0, 'Bad Axe': 1.0}
{'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1334, 'item': 'Hot Bar Serving Hardware', 'Variant OG': 5.0, 'Bad Axe': 1.0}
```

Comment: What approach have you tried so far?  It looks like you need to match up the dictionaries based on some defined key e.g. `item_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like each list only varies by `Variant OG` or `Bad Axe`, so sorting by the `item` or `item_id` and using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to iterate over items with matching keys will solve the problem:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [{'menu':'','category':'Production Item','group':'','item_id':1354,'item':'Giardiniera','Variant OG':5.0},
       {'menu':'','category':'Production Item','group':'','item_id':1355,'item':'Sweet Peppers','Variant OG':5.0},
       {'menu':'','category':'Production Item','group':'','item_id':1334,'item':'Hot Bar Serving Hardware','Variant OG':5.0},
       {'menu':'','category':'Production Item','group':'','item_id':1354,'item':'Giardiniera','Bad Axe':1.0},
       {'menu':'','category':'Production Item','group':'','item_id':1355,'item':'Sweet Peppers','Bad Axe':1.0},
       {'menu':'','category':'Production Item','group':'','item_id':1334,'item':'Hot Bar Serving Hardware','Bad Axe':1.0}]


# groupby requires the container to be sorted by the key
sortkey = lambda x: x['item_id']
lst.sort(key=sortkey)

# "key" is the common key for the items
# "items" is an iterator of the common items
for key,items in groupby(lst,key=sortkey):
    # start with an empty dict for each common key
    dct = {}
    for item in items:
        # add all key/value pairs for each common key item to the dict
        dct.update(item)
    print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1334, 'item': 'Hot Bar Serving Hardware', 'Variant OG': 5.0, 'Bad Axe': 1.0}
{'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1354, 'item': 'Giardiniera', 'Variant OG': 5.0, 'Bad Axe': 1.0}
{'menu': '', 'category': 'Production Item', 'group': '', 'item_id': 1355, 'item': 'Sweet Peppers', 'Variant OG': 5.0, 'Bad Axe': 1.0}
```

Comment: worked like a charm!  thank you sir for the wonderful and detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

It could be easier if you first divide the list_of_dictionaries into 2 different lists so that the other one contains all the 'Variant OG's and the other one all the 'Bad Axe's.

Then you can easily iterate through them e.g.

```
for variant in variant_OGs:
       for bad in bad_axes:
             if( variant['item']==bad['item']):
                   #put them into single dict
```